# Elixir - Convert strings to different types

Tags: elixir

I have a stringified value that may be an integer or boolean (`"20"`, `"true"`). I would like to cast the value to it's type, however, when I do a conversion on the wrong type, I get a runtime error:

```rb
iex> String.to_existing_atom("20")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_existing_atom("20", :utf8)

iex> String.to_integer("true")    
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("true")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to convert only integers and booleans from strings you may do something like this:

```rb
defmodule Converter do
  def convert!("true"), do: true
  def convert!("false"), do: false
  def convert!(num), do: String.to_integer(num)
end
```

Sample usage:

```rb
iex(4)> Enum.map(["20", "true", "-5", "false"], &Converter.convert!/1)
[20, true, -5, false]
```

If you are dealing with json you may want to consider using a parsing library such as [Poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison).

Answer (score 1):

By definition `String.to_existing_atom/1` will fail if there is no existing atom with such name. If you forcefully create atom for given string (be careful as atoms aren't GC-ed so you can DoS yourself by that) you need to use `String.to_atom/1`.

However if you want to parse binary and get value from it then you can use:

- [`Integer.parse/1-2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2)
- [`Float.parse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#parse/1)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [WannabeBool](https://hexdocs.pm/wannabe_bool/0.1.0/readme.html) library. Not the solution for the example, but useful to convert strings to boolean.

```
WannabeBool.to_boolean("true")
true

WannabeBool.to_boolean("false")
false
```

Comment: adding a dependency for 20 lines of code that this library provides is not worth it